# Reusable confirmation prompt in QML

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I need a confirmation or alert dialog when user presses a button. Based on if they choose 'yes' or 'no', different actions are triggered. The challenge is that I have two buttons which pops such a dialog and it's not quite straightforward how to do that in QML. Here is the code (my demo application):

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true

    function areYouSure()
    {
        prompt.visible = true
    }

    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: buttonA
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            text: "Button A"

            onClicked: areYouSure() // based on yes or no, different actions but how to tell what was pressed?
        }

        Button {
            id: buttonB
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            text: "Button B"

            onClicked: areYouSure() // based on yes or no, different actions but how to tell what was pressed?
        }
    }

    Prompt {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: prompt
        visible: false

        onCancelled: {
            console.log("Cancel was pressed")
            // but how can I tell which button's cancel as pressed?
        }

        onAccepted: {
            console.log("Accept was pressed")
            // same for which button's Ok?
        }
    }
}
```

Prompt.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle
{
    id: root
    width: parent.width

    property string message: "Are you Sure?"

    signal cancelled;
    signal accepted;


    Text{
        id: messagetxt
        text:root.message
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

    }

    Rectangle {
        id: cancelButton
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: 50
        height: 40

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Cancel"
        }
        color: "red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: {
                root.visible = false
                cancelled()
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: okButton
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        width: 50
        height: 40

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Ok"
        }
        color: "blue"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: {
                root.visible = false
                accepted()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In traditional programming, an individual dialog pops up which respond exactly to that question and than we respond to its `cancelled()` or `accepted()` signals. In QML we can't really do that, right? What is the best way to know which button was pressed? The irony is that even the right signals are emitted, we just can't seem to act on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first and foremost you should really have a look at [`Dialogs`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-dialogs-qmlmodule.html) module since it provides what would be a ready made solution for you, i.e. `MessageDialog`.

That said, you can achieve a customisation in different ways, including redefining the handlers or passing the `id`s. If the action to perform are simple (e.g. a function call) you can dynamically create even the dialog and bind the signals with the desired behaviour. Customisation can obviously go further, changing `title` and `text`.

Here is a simple example which follows the last approach and prints different texts depending on the pressed button. Once the dialog is set to not visible it is destroyed via the `destroy` function.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: win
    title: qsTr("MultiDialog")
    visible: true

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            text: "Button 1"
            onClicked: {
                var d1 = compDialog.createObject(win)
                // change "title" & "text"?
                d1.accepted.connect(function(){
                    console.info("accepted: " + text)
                })
                d1.rejected.connect(function(){
                    console.info("rejected: " + text)
                })
                d1.visible = true
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Button 2"
            onClicked: {
                var d2 = compDialog.createObject(win)
                // change "title" & "text"?
                d2.accepted.connect(function(){
                    console.info("accepted: " + text)
                })
                d2.rejected.connect(function(){
                    console.info("rejected: " + text)
                })
                d2.visible = true
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: compDialog

        MessageDialog {
            title: "May I have your attention please"
            text: "It's so cool that you are using Qt Quick."
            onVisibleChanged: if(!visible) destroy(1)
            standardButtons: StandardButton.Cancel | StandardButton.Ok
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use `Rectangle` or are forced to use it, then you can still use this approach. Dynamic creation of objects is NOT related to the usage of `MessageDialog` and can be used (and should be used) to reduce the number of objects kept instanced throughout application lifetime. Have a look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) for more details about that.

The following example uses the very same dialog component you defined (with some small modifications. As you can see the code is almost identical. I've just moved the destruction of the object at the end of the signal handlers. In this case I've also changed the value of the unique property defined in the component, i.e. `message`, to show you complete customization.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: win
    visible: true

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            text: "Button 1"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            onClicked: {
                var d1 = prompt.createObject(win)
                d1.message = text + " - Are you Sure?"
                d1.accepted.connect(function(){
                    console.info("accepted: " + text)
                    d1.destroy()
                })
                d1.rejected.connect(function(){
                    console.info("rejected: " + text)
                    d1.destroy()
                })
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Button 2"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            onClicked: {
                var d2 = prompt.createObject(win)
                d2.message = text + " - Are you Sure?"
                d2.accepted.connect(function(){
                    console.info("accepted: " + text)
                    d2.destroy()
                })
                d2.rejected.connect(function(){
                    console.info("rejected: " + text)
                    d2.destroy()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: prompt

        Rectangle {
            id: root
            anchors.fill: parent

            property string message: "Are you Sure?"

            signal rejected()
            signal accepted()

            Text{
                id: messagetxt
                text:root.message
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: cancelButton
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.left: parent.left
                width: 50
                height: 40

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "Cancel"
                }
                color: "red"

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: rejected()
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: okButton
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.right: parent.right
                width: 50
                height: 40

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "Ok"
                }
                color: "blue"

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: accepted()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your component is not inlined as I did with `Component` but it's kept in another file you can use `createComponent` as depicted in the link provided above. The code of your main window would look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: win
    visible: true
    property var prompt

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            text: "Button 1"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            onClicked: {
                var d1 = prompt.createObject(win)
                d1.message = text + " - Are you Sure?"
                d1.accepted.connect(function(){
                    console.info("accepted: " + text)
                    d1.destroy()
                })
                d1.rejected.connect(function(){
                    console.info("rejected: " + text)
                    d1.destroy()
                })
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Button 2"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            onClicked: {
                var d2 = prompt.createObject(win)
                d2.message = text + " - Are you Sure?"
                d2.accepted.connect(function(){
                    console.info("accepted: " + text)
                    d2.destroy()
                })
                d2.rejected.connect(function(){
                    console.info("rejected: " + text)
                    d2.destroy()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: prompt = Qt.createComponent("Prompt.qml");
}
```

You should always check that component creation is correcly carried out (I didn't do it for the sake of brevity). That said, the code is identical to the previous one.

Last but not least, I've noticed an error in your code: signals must **always** be declared with parenthesis, even when no parameter is emitted. It should be `signal accepted()`, not `signal accepted`, same goes for the other signal and any other signal declaration.